# Graph of polynomial problem from Gelfands Functions and Graphs

Tags: graphing-functions

Working through Gelfands Functions and Graphs but I'm stuck on a question. The question involves an image of a graph of $x^2 + px + q$ from the graph alone you need to find $p$ and $q$.

As you can see from the image below the vertex of the parabola is not known. I can find equations of graphs of parabolas with known vertex co-ordinates but is there any hints to find the equation of this graph?

[image: trinomial_graph]

Comment: You have two points on the graph: $ (4,0)$ and $(5,-3)$ and you know the equation of the parabola is $y=x^2+px+q$.  That gives you two simultaneous equations in $p$ and $q$.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: thanks very much. I had one of those 'doh!' moments when I read your comment thinking why didn't I think of that. Got the answer now. Thanks!